# apt-get vs. package/version

Tags: apt, 22.04, software-sources

I have this output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe multiverse restricted
deb      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main universe multiverse restricted
deb      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main universe multiverse restricted
deb      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-proposed main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-proposed main universe multiverse restricted
deb      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main universe multiverse restricted
```

If I do this :

```
sudo apt-get --option 'Dir::Cache="/tmp/nothingthere"' --print-uris install --reinstall qemu-system-gui/jammy-proposed 2>&1 | grep http | grep qemu-system-x86
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-x86_6.2%2bdfsg-2ubuntu6.8_amd64.deb' qemu-system-x86_1%3a6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.8_amd64.deb 10086894 MD5Sum:cec14bb2b5e45450b98c2b4708817fe9
```

But using `jammy-updates` in the place of `jammy-proposed` I do not get the 6.7 : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qemu-system-gui

Is this a bug ? If it is not, is there a simple way to get the "updates" one without changing the sources.list?

The aim is to know the files from "distribution"-"stream" to provide lists to make decision choices compare to CVE vs. bugs vs. tests vs. delivery risks for our products.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking; I do see `qemu-system-gui | 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.6 | jammy-security   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` , `qemu-system-gui | 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.7 | jammy-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` , `qemu-system-gui | 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.8 | jammy-proposed   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` available - but again not what you're asking  (ie. security, updates & proposed have different versions, which isn't unusual as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/

Comment: It seems like you want to know which package versions are patched against which CVEs, and which repositories those patched versions are located in. Is that on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but using `| grep package-name` was hidding us the fact that some dependecies were not met and so apt does not output us no path to no file.

We find other means to accomplish what we wanted to, with a loop on top of changing progressively the sources.list in this order :
"distrib"
"distrib"-security
"distrib"-updates
"distrib"-proposed.